# Generating received signal strength indicator(RSSi) using python in ubuntu

Tags: sockets, python-2.7, ubuntu, raspberry-pi, rssi

I have created a Client Server Model using Raspberry Pi and Ubuntu. RPi is the client and Ubuntu is the server. The server being run, Rpi sends a request to the server and the Ubuntu server responds to Rpi (which is an acknowledgement). This is done using socket programming in Python.

Now that the Rpi and Ubuntu are connected, I want to generate RSSI values of this connection. i.e. The client(Rpi) sends a message to Ubuntu server and once the Ubuntu server receives the message from client, I want to read the signal strength(rssi) in ubuntu server and in Rpi.

---

### client (on Raspberry Pi)

```
 `    #!/bin/bash

import socket
import os

def Main():
    host = '192.168.2.213'
    port = 5001

    server = ('192.168.2.1', 5000)

    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    s.bind((host,port))

    message = raw_input("-> ")
    for x in range(1,11):
            cmd = "iwconfig wlan1 station dump |grep -i signal | awk -F '{print $4}' | awk -F'=' {print $1}"
    while message != 'q':
            s.sendto(message, server)
            data, addr = s.recvfrom(1024)
            print 'Received from Alice :' + str(data)
            message = raw_input("-> ")
    for x in range(1,11):
            cmd = "iwconfig wlan1 station dump |grep -i signal | awk -F '{print $4}' | awk -F'=' {print $1}"
    s.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
       Main()
```

---

### Server (Ubuntu)

```
#!/usr/bin/python 


import socket
import os


def Main():
    host = '192.168.2.1'
    port = 5000

    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    s.bind((host, port))

    print "ALICE Started."
    while True:
            data, addr = s.recvfrom(1024)
            print "address of bob : " + str(addr)
            print "message from bob : " + str(data)
            data = str(data).upper()
            print "sending : " + str(data)
        for x in range (1,11):
                cmd = "iw wlan1 station dump | grep -i signal | /usr/bin/awk '{print $2}' | /usr/bin/cut -d'=' -f2"
                    dbm = int( os.popen( cmd ).read() )
            print " recieved RSSI: " + str(addr)
            s.sendto(data, addr)
    s.close()
if __name__  == '__main__':
        Main()
```

To generate RSSI values, I am trying to use iwconfig(python)to see the wireless device and dump the signal in the cmd variable. On running the code, i do not get any run time error on CLient or Server.

Can anybody guide me if i am going in the right direction to get the RSSI values.

Thanks.

Comment: Why does your first script have `#!/bin/bash`? That don't look like no Bash script to me...

Comment: Also, why are you repeating the `cmd = "iwconfig...` assignment so many times?

Comment: @MattDMo thank you. im aware that  #!/bin/bash is not necessary. also im repeating cmd in the first script because apart from initiating the connection my client script also sends a message even after receiving the response from server, i.e there is cmd in the while loop